# Display dummy password text with same number of characters as original password

Tags: javascript, html, concrete5

I have an edit user page  where I have to display some user details like User Name ,First Name,Last Name... and Password with which the user logs In.
I'm using concrete5 so I **cant** decrypt the password so as to show in password field.(`input type="password")`
I have to display a dummy password field,which should have the same number of characters as the password .Is there any idea to generate password fields having the same number of asterisks as the original password.

Comment: Can you save the `length` of original password, and then use this length to show that number of `*`

Comment: ok password length can be saved

Comment: _"I have to display some user details like <...> Password with which the user logs In."_ What? You want to show a user's password on their _"edit profile"_ page?

Comment: I think you just shouldn't bother. It will pose too many problems. For example how would you distinquish a new password from this random data? Really, just use a password field with a placeholder. Also, giving away the original password length probably is a security risk.

Comment: @Cerbrus :in asterisks format

Comment: Bad idea. Don't do it. Keeping track of password length is only a potential security problem. And what if my password is `****-****-****`?

Comment: Okay !! So i shall put password123 or something in the field ..Right ?

Comment: No, just leave it blank. Users are probably long used to how password edit/reset fields work. Prefilling it will just feel wrong to most of them (imo).

Comment: No, just use `<input name='old_password' type='password' placeholder='enter current password'>` and `<input name='password' type='password' placeholder='enter new password'>`

Comment: The placeholder should be something about "password," so people know what they're filling out. Users are dumb and they won't all have the intuition that asterisks = password here, so just go with convention.

Comment: Do you want to allow password change on this page? If yes, the number of * does not matter. If no, then showing the password length is a security issue.

Comment: I will leave the password field  empty for now!!Let the user enter it again while editing :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the password length, which is not a great security decision, I would use a static length instead. Here are a few examples of how you can use placeholders to give the user a good experience without divulging password length:

```html
<p>Use a static length password representation</p>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="*************"><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="*************"><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="*************"><br>

<p>Use prompts for the passwords instead</p>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Current Password"><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="New Password"><br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm New Password"><br>

<p>Or just leave them blank (assuming they already have labels)</p>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="password" name="password"><br>
```